# Is JSX just the HTML-like markup or the surrounding code as well?

Tags: reactjs

I have a terminology question. Let's say I have the following code:

```js
var Name = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var ranNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 200);

      return (
        <p>
          Hello, {ranNum}!
        </p>
      );
    }
});
```

When people talk about JSX, is it just the HTML-like items inside the `return`? Or does it also include the surrounding JavaScript like the `ranNum` declaration/initialization?

From reading the docs (and the proposed spec extension), JSX seems like it is just the HTML-like syntax. Everything else around it is just plain JavaScript.

Thanks,

Kirupa

Comment: HTML-XML-alike, yes and it refers to the value inside the `return`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From reading the docs (and the proposed spec extension), JSX seems like it is just the HTML-like syntax. Everything else around it is just plain JavaScript.

Yes. JSX is simply an *extension* of the JavaScript syntax. From the [spec](https://facebook.github.io/jsx/):

> JSX is a XML-like syntax extension to ECMAScript without any defined semantics. It's NOT intended to be implemented by engines or browsers. It's NOT a proposal to incorporate JSX into the ECMAScript spec itself. It's intended to be used by various preprocessors (transpilers) to transform these tokens into standard ECMAScript.